# How to do a rest-update with Many-To-One relationships

Tags: java, database, rest

i have a model like this:

Entity A has many of Entity B, Entity B has one of Entity C.
And Entity C are Unique ones.

What is the preferred rest method of updating data like this? 
So i imagine something like:

> PUT /api/persons/{id} with a json body.

But what do i do with the existing data? Do i really update it with a little code or can i create a new entry with the old id? Is that clean?

I am struggling with rest concepts and relational database concepts and dont get them really well together.

Comment: What's the semantics of update? Shall update replace the old data, shall it rather be merged with old data ?

Comment: I guess i want to merge the data. The sent data contains all it has before.

Comment: _The sent data contains all it has before_ If new data includes everything that was before, why do you want to merge?